# applyBindingsToNode and html bounds

Tags: knockout.js

I am wanting to update a view dynamically by applying applyBindingsToNode to it but it seems it must have a data-bind attached to it?  Is that true?  What if I have a button and another button with click events that needed to be registed by knockout.js.  Would I have to call applyBindingsToNode to both of the buttons?

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element1, null, app.viewModel);
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element2, null, app.viewModel);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call ko.applyBindings(viewModel, element) on a parent element and it will apply bindings to it and anything under it.